# Constraints without using auto-layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I am not using auto-layout, and I want to know if I can specify constraints between a `UILabel` and a `UITextView`. I tried what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148061/adding-constraints-without-auto-layout), but I got an error `View hierarchy unprepared for constraint`, so I looked up for that and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177262/centering-subviews-x-in-autolayout-throws-not-prepared-for-the-constraint), the accepted answer says that the views I am trying to add constraints to must be the subviews, if that is correct how can I add constraints so that the `X position` of my `UITextView` is set according to the height of `UILabel` ? I will post a picture so that it will give you all a clear idea:

[image]

Now I don't know if the `UILabel` is a single line or a couple of lines, and I want my `UITextView` to adjust it's X-position accordingly. This is the code I added, since I just learned about it please let me know if it is correct:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *xConstraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tvNewsDetails attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.lblNewsTitle attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:0.45 constant:0];

[self.tvNewsDetails addConstraints:@[xConstraint]];
```

Comment: You have to try visual formatting method.This is recommended by apple and you cannot make it done without using autolayout.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606205/uiview-with-dynamic-height-multiple-uilabel/36607158#36607158

Comment: Constraints are the things that drive autolayout. You cannot have one without the other. Do you mean you want to use constraints without interface builder?

Comment: Its not about IB, i just want to set the constraints (no auto-layout though).

Comment: @Paulw11 - So i can't add constraints without auto-layout ?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make sense. Constraints=autolayout.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Sorry, i am new to obj C, so i can't even use NSLayoutConstraint in my code ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but if you are creating your UI elements programmatically then you need to set the item's `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `false` and then you will need to add all of the constraints required to layout your items appropriately.

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

First you set leading, trailing, top, bottom for `UILabel`. In right side corner attribute inspector Line = 0 and line breaks = word wrap

then set constraints leading, trailing, top, bottom for `UITextview`. if `UITextview` height is fixed size means set height for `UITextview`.

must place both the component in `UIScrollview`.

it will flexible, while label height will increase.